# MySQL Insert Into on Duplicate Key query is not updating

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query, that I was trying to convert to an insert into...on duplicate key etc and I followed the mysql guide but for some reason it does not update my text. It does however succesfully creates new rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The purpose of the query is to add and update a small amount of text.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO fetss.ocs_extended(ocsID, internalNOTE)
            VALUES('" .(int)$_POST['id'] ."', '". $db- >quote($_POST['note_desc']) ."')
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE internalNOTE = VALUES('". $db->quote($_POST['note_desc']) ."')";
```

to be a liitle bit more simple:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO database.tablename(ID, Description)
VALUES(ID, Description) on Duplicate Key Update Description = VALUES(Description)"
```

Comment: is your id set as a unique index?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO fetss.ocs_extended(`ocsID`, `internalNOTE`)
                VALUES(%d, '%s')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                `internalNOTE` = VALUES(`internalNOTE`)",
                (int)$_POST['id'],
                $db->quote($_POST['note_desc']));
```

I used [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) to make the SQL a bit easier to read but since you want to update the description with the value from the query, you don't have to specify the value, just tell it to use the value from the insert statement by specifying that column name.

If you wanted to update it to some arbitrary string, you could do:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, desc) VALUES(1, 'testing')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
desc = 'some other string that is not testing';
```

The difference is that you don't use the [`VALUES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) function which is what the problem with your initial query was.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! When I run this query though and update my text field it actually makes a new row. So I'm not sure what's going on there

Comment: Is `ocsID` the `PRIMARY KEY`?  If not it must be a `UNIQUE` index.

Comment: There are 3 primary keys in my table and ocsID is one of them

Comment: Well its only possible to have 1 primary key in a table, if you mean the primary key is a composite index and ocsID is a part of that key, that isn't good enough to trigger the update.  It will have to use the entire key (all columns part of the primary key).  That is why it isn't working I think.

Comment: thanks I'll try to play around with the keys and values and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

use REPLACE instead of INSERT

When you use Replace, if already exists a row with duplicate key, MySQL replaces the old row values with given values

Comment: With REPLACE, it DELETEs the row first.  You'll get a new auto id, etc.

Comment: A new auto id??? I did it a lot of times in 11 years and never gived me a new auto id. If not, is a new row! Not Replace! Yes the documentation says DELETES and insert a row with de data given in REPLACE statement, but doesn't say anything about new id for auto increment columns http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: I'm dating myself.  That was fixed in 2005 :)  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10795